# libCurl x64 build problems Visual Studio 2013 (x64) Visual Studio & CMake

Tags: curl, cmake, 64-bit, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I am trying to build libCurl x64 on Windows 8.1 x64 and I am having linker errors.  I need to be able to do this as I need to create a 64 bit debug version of the library so that I can trace some strange FTP related protocol issues I am encountering.

The fundamental error output (trimmed for brevity) is as follows

> 1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64
>
> ...
>
> 2>C:\Users\jcoffey\main\extlibs\curl-7.35.0\lib\smtp.c(2174): warning
>   C4267: '+=' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of
>   data 2>  pingpong.c 2>  rtsp.c 2>  curl_threads.c 2>  warnless.c 2> 
>   hmac.c 2>  curl_rtmp.c 2>  openldap.c 2>  curl_gethostname.c 2> 
>   gopher.c 2>  Generating Code... 2>  Compiling... 2>  idn_win32.c 2> 
>   http_negotiate_sspi.c 2>  http_proxy.c 2>  non-ascii.c 2>  asyn-ares.c
>   2>  asyn-thread.c 2>  curl_gssapi.c 2>  curl_ntlm.c 2>  curl_ntlm_wb.c
>   2>  curl_ntlm_core.c 2>  curl_ntlm_msgs.c 2>  curl_sasl.c 2> 
>   curl_multibyte.c 2>  hostcheck.c 2>  bundles.c 2>  conncache.c 2> 
>   pipeline.c 2>  dotdot.c 2>  x509asn1.c 2>  http2.c 2>  Generating
>   Code... 2>  Compiling... 2>  openssl.c 2>  gtls.c 2>  vtls.c 2>  nss.c
>   2>  qssl.c 2>  polarssl.c 2>  polarssl_threadlock.c 2>  axtls.c 2> 
>   cyassl.c 2>  curl_schannel.c 2>  curl_darwinssl.c 2>  gskit.c 2> 
>   Generating Code...
>
> ...
>
> 2>x64\Debug\file.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module
>   machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' 3>------
>   Build started: Project: curl, Configuration: Debug x64 ------ 3> 
>   Building Custom Rule
>   C:/Users/jcoffey/main/extlibs/curl-7.35.0/src/CMakeLists.txt

Please help - I have searched the forums and stackoverflow for something similar but to no avail.  I was able to successfully build in x86 (win32) mode but I am having linkage errors when I target x64.

**Step 1:**
Download latest **CMake 2.8.12.2** & update the Windows **PATH** environment (in my case I am using the MINMGW32 bash shell prompt, but I get exactly the same linkage problems if I use the native visual studio 2013 x64 shell to run cmake from)

> $ export PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/CMake\ 2.8/bin

verify that the path and version of Cmake on windows

> $ cmake --version cmake version 2.8.12.2

**Step 2:**
extract curl-7.35.0 into a folder c:\temp\curl-7.35.0"  and make a parallel folder "c:\temp\curl-7.35.0\build".

**Step 3:**
Change into the build folder and run Cmake targeting "Visual Studio 12" as the desired Visual Studio Solution/project combination to create

> $ cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ../curl-7.35.0

This produces a ton of output as follows, but it does also create a workable visual studio solution targeted for a machine type X86.

> $ cmake -G "Visual Studio 12" ../curl-7.35.0
>   -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
>   -- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12
>   -- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 -- works
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:47 (message):   the curl cmake build system is poorly
>   maintained.  Be aware
>
> -- curl version=[7.35.0]
>   -- Looking for getch in ws2_32;
>   -- Looking for getch in ws2_32; - found
>   -- Looking for getch in winmm;ws2_32
>   -- Looking for getch in winmm;ws2_32 - found
>   -- Looking for cldap_open in wldap32
>   -- Looking for cldap_open in wldap32 - found
>   -- Looking for idna_to_ascii_lz in idn;winmm;ws2_32
>   -- Looking for idna_to_ascii_lz in idn;winmm;ws2_32 - not found
>   -- Looking for ldap_init in ldap;winmm;ws2_32
>   -- Looking for ldap_init in ldap;winmm;ws2_32 - not found
>   -- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the sys tem variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES
>   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
>
> -- Looking for include file ws2tcpip.h
>   -- Looking for include file ws2tcpip.h - found
>   -- Looking for include files ws2tcpip.h, winsock2.h
>   -- Looking for include files ws2tcpip.h, winsock2.h - found
>   -- Looking for 3 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdio.h
>   -- Looking for 3 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdio.h - found
>   -- Looking for 4 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., windows.h
>   -- Looking for 4 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., windows.h - found
>   -- Looking for 5 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., winsock.h
>   -- Looking for 5 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., winsock.h - found
>   -- Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/filio.h
>   -- Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/filio.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/ioctl.h
>   -- Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/ioctl.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/resource.h
>   -- Looking for 6 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/resource.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/uio.h
>   -- Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/uio.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/un.h
>   -- Looking for 8 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/un.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., arpa/tftp.h
>   -- Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., arpa/tftp.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., assert.h
>   -- Looking for 9 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., assert.h - found
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., crypto.h
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., crypto.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., des.h
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., des.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., err.h
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., err.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., errno.h
>   -- Looking for 10 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., errno.h - found
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi.h
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_generic.h
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_generic.h - not f ound
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., gssapi/gssapi_krb5.h - not foun d
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idn-free.h
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idn-free.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ifaddrs.h
>   -- Looking for 12 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ifaddrs.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., krb.h
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., krb.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libgen.h
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libgen.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libssh2.h
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., libssh2.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., limits.h
>   -- Looking for 13 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., limits.h - found
>   -- Looking for 14 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., locale.h
>   -- Looking for 14 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., locale.h - found
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., netinet/tcp.h
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., netinet/tcp.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., pem.h
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., pem.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., poll.h
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., poll.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., rsa.h
>   -- Looking for 15 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., rsa.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ssl.h
>   -- Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ssl.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdbool.h
>   -- Looking for 17 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stdbool.h - found
>   -- Looking for 21 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stropts.h
>   -- Looking for 21 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stropts.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 22 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., tld.h
>   -- Looking for 22 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., tld.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 23 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stddef.h
>   -- Looking for 23 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., stddef.h - found
>   -- Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ldap.h
>   -- Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., ldap.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/utsname.h
>   -- Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., sys/utsname.h - not found
>   -- Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idna.h
>   -- Looking for 26 include files ws2tcpip.h, ..., idna.h - not found
>   -- LDAP_H not found CURL_DISABLE_LDAP set ON
>   -- LDAP needs to be enabled to support LDAPS
>   -- Check size of size_t
>   -- Check size of size_t - done
>   -- Check size of ssize_t
>   -- Check size of ssize_t - failed
>   -- Check size of long long
>   -- Check size of long long - done
>   -- Check size of long
>   -- Check size of long - done
>   -- Check size of short
>   -- Check size of short - done
>   -- Check size of int
>   -- Check size of int - done
>   -- Check size of __int64
>   -- Check size of __int64 - done
>   -- Check size of time_t
>   -- Check size of time_t - done
>   -- Looking for basename
>   -- Looking for basename - not found
>   -- Looking for strncmpi
>   -- Looking for strncmpi - not found
>   -- Looking for alarm
>   -- Looking for alarm - not found
>   -- Looking for CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data
>   -- Looking for CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data - not found
>   -- Looking for gethostbyname
>   -- Looking for gethostbyname - found
>   -- Looking for strtoll
>   -- Looking for strtoll - found
>   -- Looking for _strtoi64
>   -- Looking for _strtoi64 - found
>   -- Looking for strerror_r
>   -- Looking for strerror_r - not found
>   -- Looking for siginterrupt
>   -- Looking for siginterrupt - not found
>   -- Looking for fork
>   -- Looking for fork - not found
>   -- Looking for freeaddrinfo
>   -- Looking for freeaddrinfo - found
>   -- Looking for freeifaddrs
>   -- Looking for freeifaddrs - not found
>   -- Looking for pipe
>   -- Looking for pipe - not found
>   -- Looking for ftruncate
>   -- Looking for ftruncate - not found
>   -- Looking for getprotobyname
>   -- Looking for getprotobyname - found
>   -- Looking for getrlimit
>   -- Looking for getrlimit - not found
>   -- Looking for idn_free
>   -- Looking for idn_free - not found
>   -- Looking for idna_strerror
>   -- Looking for idna_strerror - not found
>   -- Looking for tld_strerror
>   -- Looking for tld_strerror - not found
>   -- Looking for setlocale
>   -- Looking for setlocale - found
>   -- Looking for setrlimit
>   -- Looking for setrlimit - not found
>   -- Looking for fcntl
>   -- Looking for fcntl - not found
>   -- Looking for ioctl
>   -- Looking for ioctl - not found
>   -- Looking for setsockopt
>   -- Looking for setsockopt - found
>   -- Looking for inet_pton
>   -- Looking for inet_pton - not found
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET - Success
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL_FIONBIO
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_CAMEL_FIONBIO - Success
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_FIONBIO
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTLSOCKET_FIONBIO - Success
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_FIONBIO
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_FIONBIO - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_SIOCGIFADDR
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_IOCTL_SIOCGIFADDR - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SETSOCKOPT_SO_NONBLOCK
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SETSOCKOPT_SO_NONBLOCK - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6_SIN6_SCOPE_ID
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKADDR_IN6_SIN6_SCOPE_ID - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKLEN_T
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_SOCKLEN_T - Success
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_BOOL_T
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_BOOL_T - Success
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_FILE_OFFSET_BITS
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_FILE_OFFSET_BITS - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R - Failed
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R
>   -- Performing Curl Test HAVE_POSIX_STRERROR_R - Failed
>   -- Check size of curl_off_t
>   -- Check size of curl_off_t - failed
>   -- Check size of socklen_t
>   -- Check size of socklen_t - done
>   -- Performing Test curl_cv_recv
>   -- Performing Test curl_cv_recv - Success
>   -- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test)
>   -- Performing Test int recv(int, void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_recv_test) -  Success
>   -- Performing Test curl_cv_send
>   -- Performing Test curl_cv_send - Success
>   -- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_t est)
>   -- Performing Test int send(int, const void *, size_t, int) (curl_cv_func_send_t est) - Success
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_MSG_NOSIGNAL - Failed
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEVAL
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_TIMEVAL - Success
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_POLL_FINE
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_POLL_FINE - Failed
>   -- Check size of sig_atomic_t
>   -- Check size of sig_atomic_t - done
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_SIG_ATOMIC_T_NOT_VOLATILE
>   -- Performing Test HAVE_SIG_ATOMIC_T_NOT_VOLATILE - Success
>   -- Check size of struct sockaddr_storage
>   -- Check size of struct sockaddr_storage - failed CMake Warning (dev) at tests/CMakeLists.txt:1 (add_subdirectory):   The source directory
>
> ```
> C:/Users/jcoffey/main/extlibs/curl-7.35.0/tests/libtest
> ```
>
> does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
>
> CMake does not support this case but it used to work accidentally
>   and is   being allowed for compatibility.
>
> Policy CMP0014 is not set: Input directories must have
>   CMakeLists.txt.  Run   "cmake --help-policy CMP0014" for policy
>   details.  Use the cmake_policy   command to set the policy and
>   suppress this warning. This warning is for project developers.  Use
>   -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Warning (dev) at tests/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_subdirectory):
>   The source directory
>
> ```
> C:/Users/jcoffey/main/extlibs/curl-7.35.0/tests/server
> ```
>
> does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.
>
> CMake does not support this case but it used to work accidentally
>   and is   being allowed for compatibility.
>
> Policy CMP0014 is not set: Input directories must have
>   CMakeLists.txt.  Run   "cmake --help-policy CMP0014" for policy
>   details.  Use the cmake_policy   command to set the policy and
>   suppress this warning. This warning is for project developers.  Use
>   -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done
>   -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/jcoffey/main/extlibs/curl-7.35.0-build

**Step 4:**
Within Visual Studio change the target type to x64 using the configuration manager (where I had to select a new platform and I selected X64 and copied the settings from Win32). This is a pretty straight forward step that is used to target an X64 machine target, so as not to confuse, I have not included the step by step details here.

**Step 5**
Select the solution and rebuild all from Visual Studio 2013 and the output above will ensue.

Side note: Although I do not really need SSL for now, it would be nice to know how to tell CMake where the location of the LIBSSL things are located (I downloaded a package of pre-built libraries (both 32 and 64 bit including the SSL and other libraries) from http://www.confusedbycode.com/curl/, however these are release mode and I need to be able to debug libCurl to see what is going on with some strange problems I am encountering.  I am a newbie when it comes to configuring CMake however it looks to be a really promising tool for those of us that target multiple platforms but prefer to develop on windows.  It certainly is easier than the gnu autotools.

Comment: `Within Visual Studio change the target type to x64 using the configuration manager` in this case you need to use `Visual Studio 12 Win64` generator

Comment: Read my complete posting, from step 4, you can see I already tried that and I am getting the problem: fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Comment: `Visual Studio 12` and `Visual Studio 12 Win64` is different generators. AFAIK you can't generate project with `Visual Studio 12` and switch to `x64`. Try `cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64" ../curl-7.35.0`

Comment: Well Done, that actually worked, I never realized that I could append the "Win64" string to the generator string. Thanks - very useful, now the next challenge will be tackling the OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR - but I suspect that is not going to be difficult (although I will need to make sure that these libraries are also built in Win64).  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the CMake generated solution file was not expecting X64 as a potential target.  I found a slight variant on the problem here.

[enter link description here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e549b76f-88fd-4314-99b6-d1ba4a3943a7/module-machine-type-x64-conflicts-with-target-machine-type-x86?forum=vcgeneral)

This is a pic of the X64 Command Line Options - as you can see after I changed the configuration manager to use X64 the

[image: Command Line - Additional Options uses incorrect machine 'X86']

[image: Command Line - Additional Options manually changed machine to 'X64']

After making these changes the project finally linked and I was able to generate a debug version of the library.

Comment: How did you tell nmake to cd into winbuild and then run Makefile.vc?

Comment: # build libCurl libraries (release & debug) 
(1) from extlibs/curl-7.44.0 with VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt:
(2) cd \Users\Johnc\main\extlibs\curl-7-44.0\winbuild
(3) nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=14 MACHINE=x64 GEN_PDB=yes
(4) nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll VC=14 MACHINE=x64 DEBUG=yes GEN_PDB=yes

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question. How were you able to set up libcurl to build within Visual Studio? Every time I try to build the project, it fails saying it can't find ../<some folder>.

Answer (score 3):

The trick for building 64-bit libcurl with on a clean x64 / Win 8.1 / VS2013 box is to *first run the Visual Studio vcvars.bat batch file **with the "amd64"** argument.* This sets up the make environment properly.

*Then* you can run the "nmake..." command as outlined in `winbuild\BUILD.WINDOWS.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (`module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'`) when building CURL from command line in the folder "curl-7.40.0\winbuild" as described by the file "BUILD.WINDOWS.txt" there. I used the following command line: `nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll ENABLE_WINSSL=no ENABLE_IDN=no GEN_PDB=yes ENABLE_SSPI=no MACHINE=x64 DEBUG=no`. It specifies "Using the Visual Studio command prompt Shell", but ... there are more of them: "Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt" does not work, "Visual Studio 2005 x64 Win64 Command Prompt" does (for 64-bit). It worked for me with Visual Studio 2005, but they say it only needs "Platform SDK".

Answer (score 0):

Place this script in Curl's source directory (I name it winbuild.bat) and run it if you don't need the curl project to compile with the rest of your solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
CD winbuild
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll WITH_DEVEL=..\..\dll64 VC=12 WITH_SSL=dll GEN_PDB=yes MACHINE=X64
CD ..
EXIT /B 0
```