# Couldn't build DLL of CURL library (C++) for x64 bit machine

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2008

This question is about curl library building for 64 bit machine.
Searched a lot in Google, but facing some errors.

Below are the things done so far.

-> Download CURL sources from below link.
  https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.52.1.zip

-> Extract the zip to curl-7.52.1 directory.
  Open "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt" from Start -> Program Files -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

-> Run below command to change to curl downloaded directory.

```
$(WorkDir)\curl-7.52.1\winbuild>
```

-> Run below command to build curl library.

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll machine=x64
```

-> After the build command, got below error:

```
..\builds\libcurl-vc-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib/file.obj : fatal e
rror LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'

NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe"' : return code '0x458'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Could not found suitable solution for above errors.

It would be highly appreciated if someone can help to resolve the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer didn't work, please write the answer that worked to help others with it. If my answer worked, tick it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio there are environment variables that you have to set to get either x86 or x64 compiler. There are multiple ways to set these environment variables:

1. You have to find the batch file `vcvarsall.bat`, and use it to import the correct environment variables
2. You have to find the shortcut that starts a command prompt with 64-bit command prompt tools. The following is a screenshot from [my blog](https://blog.afach.de/?page_id=399) explaining this:

[image]

So, you have to find that shortcut or [learn how to use vcvarsall.bat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). There are tons of tutorials about it there.

One important thing to keep in mind is that prior to Visual Studio 2012, 64-bit was not available in Visual Studio Express, so unless you have Visual Studio 2008 Professional, this won't be possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your details answer. I have tried according to your suggestion.
Opened "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt" command prompt from start menu and run below command from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\" directory:
'vcvarsall.bat x64'
And below from "curl-7.52.1\winbuild" directory:
'nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=dll machine=x64'
But still getting the same error.

Comment: @gsmaker I can see that you're linking to some ssl library. Is that compiled with a 64-bit compiler? Notice that binary compatibility is a necessity that entails that everything you link to is 64-bit.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was out of work for few days.<br/>
According to your suggestion, couldn't build libcurl successfully.  
But solved the issue according to below link:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398914/how-do-i-build-libcurl-for-64-bit-windows-in-using-visual-studio-2010?answertab=active#tab-top  

According to above link I was missing to set correct env variable using the bat file. I have used vcvarsx86_amd64.bat file to set env variable.

Comment: The Visual Studio Command Prompts do not control the target architecture. They select the bitness of the tool chain. The target architecture is set through compiler/linker options and/or environment variables.

Comment: @IInspectable we don't disagree. If you got it differently from what you said it's just a figure of speech.